# Doubt regarding an infinite set from N->N mapping becoming a many one onto function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ be a function defined by
}
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &x = 1 \\ x-1, &x > 1\end{cases}$$

Answer given as many one and onto

My doubt is how come this is many one and onto

I accept that is infinite set

Even when when we try to map an element in domain with an element in codomain there will be one element left in codomain which will not have a preimage.

So how come this be a surjective many one function

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Even when when we try to map an element in domain with an element in codomain there will be one element left in codomain which will not have a preimage" : which element are you referring to in the specific case?

Comment: It's not one-to-one, because $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2 - 1 = 1$. Surely this is not controversial?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Ya ..what you are mentioning is right ..But if i a maping an element ..keep on maping there will be one n+1 element in codomain which  i will lack to map with domain at an instant like always the cardinality of codomain will be greater than the range right ...

Comment: @TheoBendit ..i also said so .. but my doubt is how come it is onto

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks for formatting

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio ..Can you give me some reference material on understanding onto functions of infinite sets ...like this

Comment: Part of the nature of infinity is $\infty = c \cdot \infty$ and $\infty = \infty \pm c$  for any positive, finite c.  Infinity does not obey all the traditional algebra laws.

Comment: You should read up on Hilbert hotel.  You have to ask yourself why there will be one left over.  The only reason you think there will be one left over is because you think there is will be a last one mapped (and as it is the last one mapped nothing to map to it).  But the most basic concept of an *infinite* set is there *isn't* a last element.  "..keep on maping there will be one n+1 element in codomain " Which $n$ is that?  Wouldn't $n+1$ be mapped frome $n+2\to (n+2)-1 = n+1$ and so on.  Again there is no last $n$.

Comment: "t like always the cardinality of codomain will be greater than the range right "  The cardinality of the domain is $infite$.  The cardinality of codomain is $infinite - 1$.  Are you claiming $infinite - 1 $ is differen cardinality as $infinite$?

Comment: And the simple definition  of onto:   $f: A \to B$ is onto if for each $b\in B$ there is a $a\in A$ were $f(a)=b$.  So for every $w\in \mathbb N$ is there some $m \in \mathbb M$ so that $f(m)=w$?  Solve for $m$.  Either $m=1$ and $f(m)=1$ and $w=1$ (okay if $w=1$) or $f(m)=m-1=w$ and therefore $m = w+1$. That works... for every $w \in \mathbb N$ we have $w+1 \in \mathbb N$ and $w+1> 1$ so $f(w+1) = w$.  So... EVERY ELEMENT OF $\mathbb N$ HAS (at least) ONE PREIMAGE.  That's the definition of onto, isn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even when when we try to map an element in domain with an element in codomain there will be one element left in codomain which will not have a preimage.

You just wrote this statement as if it's an obvious incontrovertible fact. Can you *prove* this statement? Which element of the domain, exactly are we talking about? Which element does not have a preimage?

---

The above element does not have an answer, of course.

The elements of the domain are simply numbers, and for each number $n$, the number $n+1$ can easily be shown to be its preimage.

Comment: ya thanks ...makes sense ..Can you provide resources proving questions of this sort...Thanks a lot @5xum

Comment: @MidhunRaj Just about any introductory book into set theory should do this.

Comment: Google Hilbert Hotel.   The entire puzzle of hilbert hotel is simply this concept.